# Can yii2 model rules facilitate validation of only one admin role per team?

Tags: yii, yii2

In my system users can have one of many roles and belong to one of many teams.

Is it possible, with the model rules, to allow the assignment of only one admin role per team?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, the role Admin and team X should be unique together.

```
[['role', 'team'], 'unique', 'when' => function($model){
    return $model->role === User::ROLE_ADMIN;
}],
```

If you add the above rule to the model rules, then it will check if both role and team are unique on the condition that the role is admin.